# SQL Query to select a value between two known strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL query to get the value between two known strings in a `text` column.
The column name is **d_info** and the table name is **Details**.

The *text* is an `XML` fragment, but stored as a `text` value.
What I need is to get the value between the bookends `<nettoeinkommen>` and `</nettoeinkommen>` which is `718` in this example.
I also need the output to be saved in new column named `income` with data type `float(8)`.

```
land>DE</land></wohnanschrift><taetigkeit>rentner</taetigkeit><dkbkundenstatus><bestandskunde>false</bestandskunde></dkbkundenstatus><haushaltsangaben><einnahmen><einkommen><nettoeinkommen>718</nettoeinkommen></einkommen><kindergeld>0</kindergeld><vermietungverpachtungnetto>0</vermietungverpachtungnetto><elterngeld>0</elterngeld><rentenunbefristet>0</rentenunbefristet><unselbststaendigetaetigkeit>740</unselbststaendigetaetigkeit><geringfuegigebeschaeftigung>0</geringfuegigebeschaeftigung></einnahmen><ausgaben><warmmiete>550</warmmiete><ratenimmobilienfinanzierung>0</ratenimmobilienfinanzierung>
```

I tried this code:

`SELECT cast(SUBSTRING(d_info, CHARINDEX('<nettoeinkommen>', d_info)
, CHARINDEX('</nettoeinkommen>', d_info) - CHARINDEX('<nettoeinkommen>', d_info)) as float(8)) as income
from dbo.Details`

But it's returning an `Error converting data type varchar to real.`

When I remove the `cast` function, the script works but it returns `<nettoeinkommen>718` instead of only `718`.

Thanks.

Comment: I think by text you really mean varchar but why are you storing xml as text in the first place? Have you tried casting your string as xml? Then you can query for any property you want.

Comment: @SeanLange  The `XML` is incomplete, it's only a fragment and it's saved in a `text` column. I've only read access, just querying..

Comment: You should avoid using the text datatype. it has been deprecated in favor of nvarchar(max) for more than a decade. It is a real pain to work with because you have to constantly convert it to varchar. And why are you storing only a fragment of your xml? That just sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: @SeanLange  is correct with both hints. I see a lot of people working with poor designed legacy projects and extend these using hacks or whatever, growing ever worse. Get the root of the problem and change the design or talk to the owner of the project to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is starting at the start of the tag not the end of it.

```
 SELECT cast(
   SUBSTRING(
     d_info, 
     CHARINDEX('<nettoeinkommen>', d_info) + len('<nettoeinkommen>'),
     CHARINDEX('</nettoeinkommen>', d_info) - (CHARINDEX('<nettoeinkommen>', d_info) + len('<nettoeinkommen>'))
   ) as float(8)) as income
 from dbo.Details
```

you might even have these defined in variables:

```
 SELECT cast(
   SUBSTRING(
     d_info, 
     CHARINDEX(@startTag, d_info) + len(@startTag),
     CHARINDEX(@endTag, d_info) - (CHARINDEX(@startTag,d_info)+ len(@startTag))
   ) as float(8)) as income
 from dbo.Details
```

I think the code is much easier to understand with the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the length of your opening tag  from the start index and subtract from the length of your substring statement:

```
SUBSTRING(d_info, CHARINDEX('<nettoeinkommen>', d_info)+16,  
CHARINDEX('</nettoeinkommen>', d_info) - CHARINDEX('<nettoeinkommen>', d_info)-16)
```

Comment: should be 16, not 15 :)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, you are querieing plain xml data, for such purpose sql-server provides xquery functionality:

```
SELECT CAST(r.d_info AS XML).value('(/haushaltsangaben/einnahmen/einkommen/nettoeinkommen)[1]', 'decimal(19,2)')
FROM
(
    SELECT '<taetigkeit>rentner</taetigkeit>
<dkbkundenstatus>
    <bestandskunde>false</bestandskunde>
</dkbkundenstatus>
<haushaltsangaben>
    <einnahmen>
        <einkommen>
            <nettoeinkommen>718</nettoeinkommen>
        </einkommen>
    </einnahmen>
</haushaltsangaben>' AS d_info
) AS r
```

If you intend to query more info from your source, you will end up with a bunch of stacked substring, patindex functions or even your own defined functions. This should be more readable and mantainable.

Using XQuery: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type

As for your initial issue The `SUBSTRING` function in SQL returns the subset from a string starting from a given index for a specific length. For example `SELECT SUBSTRING('whatever',5,4)` returns 'ever'. 
In case of `CHARINDEX` it gives the index for the first found match of a given pattern within a string. Example `SELECT CHARINDEX('ever','whatever')` should return 5, as 'ever' starts at the fifth position in 'whatever').

Now in your case you need to add the length of `'<nettoeinkommen>'` to the starting charindex and substract the length of `'</nettoeinkommen>'` from the length of the substring:

Also consider using decimal or numeric type instead of float, if you need to precise calculations: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: you should show how to do it using xpath -- that would be a much better answer than mine!

Comment: I know.  Let me restate my point.  SO users have a low attention span -- if you re-wrote this answer to only include the xpath solution and explained  why it was better than the sub-string, this would be an better answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I still kept the hint how substring and charindex works, might help someone. As for the low attention span, I had to laugh because lately I have the impression this applies to a lot of people.

Comment: I'm sorry... what were we talking about?